# How to change the background color of a UIButton when tapped in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, ibaction

```
ViewController: UIViewController {
   @IBAction func like(sender: AnyObject) {
       like(backgroundColor!) = UIColor.greenColor()
   }
}
```

I want to chanage the color of UIbutton"like button" :
White is the default "not tapped or unlike"
green when is tapped.

How do you change a buttons background colour when it is tapped using Swift?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The button isn't `like` -- that's the method's name. You can access the button through `sender`.

```
@IBAction func like(sender: AnyObject) {
    (sender as UIButton).backgroundColor = UIColor.green
}
```

Or more concise:

```
@IBAction func like(button: UIButton ) {
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
}
```

Comment: It works like magic ! but why the color is not filling the png image?       thank you very much

Comment: @JAMESMATHEO12 I don't know exactly what you mean, but it sounds as if your png image isn't actually transparent where you expect it to be.

Comment: @JAMESMATHEO12 Oh, well a UIButton is naturally rectangular so you'll have to add a corner radius to make it circular instead.